# have 200 lines in an excel spread sheet and i need to call them in a wp7 app

Tags: c#, excel, windows-phone-7, storage

I have strings (4 columns and 20 rows) in an excel sheet and I need to call there position in an app, such as column 2 row 159.

I was wondering what someone thought about my options and how I would move this data.  I have looked into:
plain 2 dimensional array
sqlite
linq
dictionary hash table

It felt like they all required  almost all manual data entry which I am trying to avoid.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Where is the sheet?  It's not at all clear from your question what you're trying to do.

Comment: I just have the sheet that I made on my computer, it is just a generic excel sheet and I want to be able to use it within my app development, the sheet is a matrix of numbers and I want to call these numbers based on the user selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to take the data in your Excel spreadsheet and make it available to your WP7 application, this should be a straightforward process.

Firstly, I would save it in CSV format, this is the most accessible format for applications to read the data. Add it to your project as a [resource and load it within your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851673/silverlight-wp7-loading-a-resource), then use a [CSV parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library) to load it into memory. You can then access it directly based on user input.